# Shopware 6: How to add custom PHP code to frontend / theme (eg. footer)

Tags: php, frontend, themes, shopware, shopware6

What is the best way, to add custom PHP code to my Shopware 6 Shop and how to do this?
I need the code executed in all pages (so maybe simply add to the footer or header).

Sample code:

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
    echo 'hello world ' . $i . '<br>';
}
?>
```

I need it, adding some php scripts to the frontend / theme.

I have tried to create a plugin, but I did not find out, if it is possible and where to integrate my PHP code to execute in the footer or other pages.

**Update:**

- Info: removed the part for what purpose / why I need this. So some comments below this Questions can be ignored.

Solution from @Feanor works perfect! It solved all my problems.
Simple way to reproduce this, use console with:

```
bin/console plugin:create YourPluginName
```

Only yes to "Subscriber Event". Plugin refresh, install and activate.
Then just add

```
use Shopware\Storefront\Event\StorefrontRenderEvent;
```

to the MySubscriber.php and replace the other code with the code from Feanor

Create "YourPluginName/src/Resources/views/storefront/layout/footer/footer.html.twig", add the rest of the code and have fun =)

Comment: You can definitely read the parameters with JS > [See this link](https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/). If that does not work, you might be able to [customize the templates](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/customize-templates.html)

Comment: I will check, if one of the methods will work with hidden GET parameters. (They are not visible in the browser URL but you can read them it with PHP). Customizing the template is not the problem. But I need real PHP code for some of my scripts. If I am right, you can only use the Symphony parsed code.

Comment: After some testing, I have not found a solution with JS only for hidden GET Parameters. More details and sample code: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77993578/23062645

Comment: Why is the param hidden? What is the point of that (it's a GET parameter, they are by nature visible in the URL). Maybe you should re-think that whole setup..

The templates are written in Twig if the documentation is correct, can't you just add your custom code as Twig in the template? [Twig documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/)

Comment: It's for filtering internal traffic. If that parameter is set, internal traffic will not be captured by analytics. There is an internal ip filter which appends the needed parameter automatically to all urls which are called in our company. But on the other side I have to hide this parameter, because of avoiding copy and paste and send to other people like customer via mail or others. We are working with Shopware 6, so edit the php code of the template / index file is not as easy as in the previous version of shopware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there will be such solution. First, you should override current footer template. You neeed to create file in your plugin path views/storefront/layout/footer/footer.html.twig. My example is looking so

```
 {% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/layout/footer/footer.html.twig' %}
 {% block layout_footer_inner_container %}
 {{ parent() }}
 <div class="custom">{{customFooter|raw}}</div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Second, you need to create a subscriber to the event Shopware\Storefront\Event\StorefrontRenderEvent I implemented it such way and it works

```
 /**
 * @return string[]
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [StorefrontRenderEvent::class=>'onFooterLoad'];
}


/**
 * @param StorefrontRenderEvent $event
 * @return void
 */
public function onFooterLoad($event){
    $result = '';
    for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
        $result.='hello world ' . $i . '<br>';
    }
    $event->setParameter('customFooter',$result);
}
```

Then this code will be executed on every frontend page. I don't provide services.xml and I think, you know, how to configure it and to implement subscriber class. Good luck with implementing it.

Comment: This works perfect. After two weeks of headache THIS was the solution I was searching for. I have added some informations to my question. Thank you so much.